# Real life analysis - how to break down revenue growth drivers

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, economics, utility

**Real life growth driver analysis problem**

**I am getting two Answers via two Methods. I would like to know which is Correct & why the other is Wrong.**

To really simplify this problem let's say there is a farm that produce and sell apples. Both the price and quantity sold increase from one month to another.

I want to quantify the contributions of each component to the growth. In other words, how much of the $44 came from the price increase and how much came from the quantity increase?

**Data for the problem**

Sold in May: 10 apples

Sold in Aug: 12 apples

Price in May: $4

Price in Aug: $7

Revenue in May: 10*4= $40

Revenue in Aug: 12*7= $84

Revenue growth = $44

---

**The logical approach** (does not work)

Through trial and error I've got to a solution that gives me the right solution but I can't wrap my head around the logic of it.

May Revenue: 10 apples * 4$ =  $40

Keeping quantity fixed (Price change): 10 apples * $7 =  $70

Keeping price fixed (Quantity change): 12 apples * $4 = $48

Isolated Price growth: 70-40 = $30

Isolated Quantity Growth: 48-40 = $8

The problem is that 8 and 30 does not sum to the growth of 44, so I'm missing something here.

---

**The approach that works** (but not logical to me)

Using the same method as in the previous approach I'm altering but not with May as the base.

May Revenue: 10 apples * $4 = $40

Keeping quantity fixed (Price change): 10 apples * $7 =  $70

Aug Revenue: 12 apples * $7 = $84

Keeping price fixed (Quantity change): 10 apples * $7 = $70

Isolated Price growth: 70-40 = $30

Isolated Quantity Growth: 84-70 = $14

This solution gives me the exact difference that I'm looking for ($44) but I don't understand how, and does it make sense?

Can someone math savvy please explain to me how I should make sense of this?

For me it makes sense to use May as the base and assume everything equal except one parameter at a time, but it doesn't give me the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

### What is going Wrong here :

Issue with your "not-working-approach" is that you are not accounting for the Combined Contribution.

Here is my analogy to highlight that :
When we have $(a+b)$ & want to square that , it will not match squaring the Individual Parts $a^2$ & $b^2$ & adding. We are leaving out the Combined Part $2ab$.

In more general terms :
When we want to multiply $(a+b)$ & $(c+d)$ , it is not enough to multiply each Part to get $ac+bd$ , we are leaving out the Cross Parts $ad$ & $bc$.

That is why you are getting smaller total.

### Correct Way :

Let $(10)(4)=40$ & $(10+2)(4+3)=84$ be the revenues in the 2 months.
Subtract the two ( after multiplication ) to get :
$(10)(4)+(10)(3)+(2)(4)+\color{red}{(2)(3)} - (10)(4)$
$+(10)(3)+(2)(4)+\color{red}{(2)(3)}$
$+30+8+\color{red}{(2)(3)}$
$+38+\color{red}{(2)(3)}$

The highlighting indicates the Combined Part which you left out earlier.

We should Share that too between the two.
You can take it Proportionally $2:3$ which gives $2.4+3.6$ , or Equally $3+3$ or Some other way to Share.
I might take it Equally . which is easy , to get $30+3=33$ & $8+3=11$ & $33+11=44$.

### Better Way :

We should look to get **Percentage Contributions** here , $P_1$ , Percentage of revenue growth due to Quantity & $P_2$ , Percentage of revenue growth due to Price , such that $P_1+P+2=100$.

In your Case , my tweak to the "working-approach" gives $33+11=44$ , then that is $100 \times 33/44 = 75\%$ & $100 \times 11/44 = 25\%$ , where $75\%+25\%=100\%$.